# Quickest way to store values in Android SQLite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I need to store simultaneous readings from 10 sensors into a SQLite database at about 100Hz. Which means I need to store about 1000 readings a second into the database.

I've tried putting the database insert method in a Service running in its own process but I can only collect about 3.5 seconds worth of data. I think the Service is being killed at that point.

I am not using database transactions to insert the data. Just individual calls of INSERT INTO... Is it crucial to use transactions?

Is it necessary to run the database inserts in a separate process? Can I just run them in a new thread off the main process?

I can provide code if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use transactions, and "chunk" your requests by performing multiple inserts in the same transaction.  You'll have to play with the number of inserts, but I would start at 1000 inserts per transaction, and tweak it from there.

Transactions are extremely slow, if you want to insert one record at a time.  The reason for this is that SQLite waits for the data to be written to disk before completing the transaction, and so has to wait for the disk platters to spin completely around, during which time the disk is essentially inactive.

On a 7200 RPM hard drive, this essentially limits transactions to 60 per second.

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19

Comment: Note that Android devices do not have 7200rpm hard drives. Flash is slow, particularly on Android 2.2 on down, where we are gated by the YAFFS2 filesystem. That being said, transactions are still crucial, even more so given the speed of the storage.

Comment: I did not know you could put so many inserts into a single transaction. I will give that a shot. Thanks for the quick replies!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to store simultaneous readings from 10 sensors into a SQLite database at about 100Hz

If you are referring to Android's sensors, I am uncertain you will actually get data delivered to you that quickly.

> I've tried putting the database insert method in a Service running in its own process

Do not use a separate process. You are adding overhead for no benefit.

Do your database I/O from whatever component is registered with your sensors. If that's a service, fine.

> I can only collect about 3.5 seconds worth of data. I think the Service is being killed at that point.

Then you have bigger problems. Processes containing running services will not be killed 3.5 seconds after launch. Somehow, your service implementation is messed up.

> I am not using database transactions to insert the data

As Mr. Harvey points out, transactions are essential for performance.

> Is it crucial to use transactions?

Yes.

> Is it necessary to run the database inserts in a separate process?

Not only is it not necessary, it borders on the ridiculous.

> Can I just run them in a new thread off the main process?

Yes.

Comment: I'm getting readings from an Arduino microprocessor that sends signals via Bluetooth. I'm using a BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() method to capture the readings and send them to the database.

Comment: @wasatch14: "I'm using a BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() method to capture the readings and send them to the database" -- the only way I can see this working is if you have that `BroadcastReceiver` registered by a `Service` via `registerReceiver()`. The service would fork a thread listening on a `LinkedBlockingQueue` or something to aggregate your data and flush it to the database using a transaction.